# Configure intellitest to use just the one test project in Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: c#, testing, xamarin, automated-tests, pex

So, I am playing with intellitest in Visual Studio 2015 RC, but something I see happening irks me and I would like to know how to disable this action. When I select to run intellitest and then go to either apply a fix or save a test result, intellitest auto-creates a second project where the changes should be applied. After having this happen so often, my solution file went from having just the two projects(Website and WebsiteTest) to having over 10 other duplicates of the WebssiteTest project in my solution file. Is there a way to disable this behaviour? I would like to know please.
[image]

A second issue I keep having is my intelliTest Projects continually include Android and Xamarin ability in the main Test and TestCopy projects, a behavior I am not really happy with. Is there a way to disable this please??

Thanks in advance

Comment: The first issue is being addressed in the next upcoming release.  Regarding the second issue please see workaround in VS 2015 RC release notes: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=524375 …. See “Known issues” in “Unit testing”. This too will be addressed at the next upcoming release.

Answer (score 1):

Just circling back to let you know that this has since been fixed at the Visual Studio RTM release. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: [This still seems to be an issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36377316/234910). Is that right?