# How to Tell IntelliTest which Project to Store Generated Tests In?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intellitest

I have a sample project for which I wish to use IntelliTests.
Though I've created a project to house the generated tests, IntelliTest seems to ignore it and create a new project with another testing framework and settings.
**Is there a way to tell IntelliTest which project to use?**

Here are the steps I've taken:

In my project there is one class with a single method.
I have first right clicked within the method and selected `Create IntelliTest` from the context menu.
Then I've create a test project using these settings:

[image]

I've now right click within the method again, and selected `Run IntelliTest` from the context menu.
After the tests have been generated, I select all of them, and click on the `save` icon.
IntelliTest now wrongly creates an new project with VS tests.
It complete ignores the previous project created as well as all the setting (see picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ran Create IntelliTest on your product code, you would have noticed a test project with a .cs file and a parameterized unit test within it (look for the method decorated with [PexMethod]. Do a “Run IntelliTest” on that method and IntelliTest will know to save the resultant tests into that project.

In the workflow you describe, you do “Run IntelliTest” on product code again. That is treated as a fresh exploration.

Please see here for some context:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/07/25/unit-test-generators-extensibility-hats-off-to-our-community/

Comment: I see. The problem is that [there is no .cs file in the generated test project](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TOcvB.png). I've tried clicking inside the method, on the method name, inside the test, on the test name. No .cs file. This is regardless of the chosen settings.

Comment: I noticed in the linked post that you were able to get it working by restoring the default templates. I have left a comment there - the next time, you see that error dialog, can you report it using the Visual Studio IDE's Send-a-Smile feature, please.